# How to express php script in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am running an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request on an web application and then displaying an appropriate [html](/questions/tagged/html) content using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

I am getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF` on the following line. Please can someone advise?  `$tr_active` contains html code.

```
 document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML = '<div id="editWrap"><?php echo $tr_active; ?></div>';
```

Comment: what contains `$tr_active`?

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: Is this the last php line of your code?

Comment: its just a php variable that contains html code